# CASE in a SELECT statement and multiple expression at THEN

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

[CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)  syntax.

```
SELECT 
   ID,
   CASE 
      WHEN ID != 2 THEN 'Others'
      ELSE ColorName
   END AS Name
FROM ColorTable
```

This gives me the following result:

```
ID - Name 
1 - Others
2 - Red
3 - Others
4 - Others
```

My requirement is to increment 'Others' by a value by one:

```
ID - Name 
1 - (1)Others
2 - Red
3 - (2)Others
4 - (3)Others
```

I have tried the following code but it failed:

```
DECLARE @Count INT = 1
SELECT 
   ID,
   CASE 
      WHEN ID != 2 THEN '(' + CONVERT(varchar(10), @Count)   + ')Others' SET @Count = @Count + 1
      ELSE ColorName
   END AS Name  
FROM ColorTable
```

**Any suggestions? How will it give such result?**

Comment: may be much easier to do this in the presentation layer (whatever full programming language you're using on top of the database layer). also: "syntex"?

Comment: Look at one of the built in ranking functions like [`ROW_NUMBER`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I agree that you should do this in the presentation layer, you could do it using ROW_NUMBER:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ID = 2 
        THEN ColorName 
        ELSE '(' + CAST(
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
            (
                PARTITION BY CASE WHEN ID = 2 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
                ORDER BY ID
            ) AS varchar) + ')Others' 
    END AS Name
FROM ColorTable
ORDER BY ID
```